# I'm getting a strange popup when USB flash drives are plugged in

Tags: usb-flash-drive, virus, autorun

**Is anyone familiar with the following problem?  How can I diagnose this further the next time I see it?**

I'm getting a strange popup whenever any type of USB removable storage device is plugged into a particular Windows XP Pro workstation.  This includes USB flash drives or Android phones.  Here is a picture of the popup:

[image]

This computer is used by multiple people, none of whom have admin privileges and it is not connected to the internet.  The computer is running Symantic Endpoint Security but it is not seeing viruses.

In regards to phones, it only seems to happen to unrooted Android phones.  All of my phones are rooted and has never caused this popup, however all of my coworkers phones are unrooted and do cause the popup.  There doesn't seem to be any distinguishing characteristic for the thumb drives although I will say that I plugged in a thumb drive that was fresh out of the package and it triggered the popup so it seems to me that whatever the problem, it is on the computer and not on the drives.  Also, these same drives do not cause popups on other similar workstations.

I've gone into the event viewer immediately after this happens but don't see any relevant information.  A Google search for the error message came up blank.

Comment: Does it do it if you disable XP's autorun/autoplay?

Comment: I have not tried that since the problem started.  I updated my question with some background info to explain why.  I am assuming that this may have been the start of the problem (how the computer got infected) but is no longer relevant because inserting a blank, fresh from the package, thumb drive caused it.  I took this to mean the issue is on the computer and only being triggered by inserting the drive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sure looks like a virus. Try this site for a net virus scan: http://www.kaspersky.com/virusscanner.

Yours may just not be picking it up (you do have the latest update, do you not?).

Comment: Yes it's up to date.  The computer is not connected to the internet but I have scanned it with portable Kaspersky and Avira from my thumb drive.

Comment: Apparently my thumb drive was not as updated as it should be.  It was a virus.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @matt - Great. I'd appreciate an accept.

Comment: Hmmm, strange, I clicked the checkmark but I guess it didn't take.  Sorry.